# Cosmos DB - create document only if count < CONST

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a web application where customers create records.
These records are saved in Cosmos DB.
Each record is saved as a separate document.
The partitioning key of the database is customer ID.

I want to limit the number of records each customer can save to CONST.
Therefore, I want to perform the following atomic operation in Cosmos DB:

- get number of documents where customerID is X
- Only if number of documents < CONST, create new document.

I want this operation to be atomic so there won't be a situation where the customer has more than CONST documents in the database.

If I separate this to 2 distinct calls to cosmos DB, then there can be a situation where 2 instances query the dB for the same customer,see that number of documents is (CONST - 1) and therefore they both add a document.

Is it possible to do this operation atomically? How?

I tried to look into stored procedures but I'm not sure if this is the correct direction. Will it be possible to achieve this using it?

Comment: What's the partition key for the records you are trying to create? Is it the customer id?

Comment: Have you tried this via SQL API? SELECT value count(c.id) FROM c where c.id = "A"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "check number of records" - where are these records: in the payload in your app? Records already in the database? If it's the former, you will have to make the decision based on the payload, as it has nothing to do with the database itself. If the latter, you can query the count of documents for your user, and then make a decision based on that. Just note: this may or may not be atomic, depending on your partitioning scheme; if your customer data spans partitions, then there is no atomic operation available.

Comment: tl;dr please edit your question to provide more specifics, along with details around what you've tried, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Edited my question - all customer records are in the same partition. I couldn't find a way of doing this atomically, without 2 distinct calls to the db